# Sorting of Field having special characters in SoLR

Tags: java, solr, solrnet

i am new at SoLR indexing.
I want to sort location field which have different values.it also contains values which starts with 'sAmerica, #'Japan, %India and etc.

Now when i sort this field i do want to consider special characters like 's,'#,!,~ and etc.
i want sorting which will ignore this chars and returns results like 
America at 1st position,  %India at 2nd   and   #'Japan at 3rd position..

How to make it possbile? i am using PatternReplaceFilterFactory,but don't know about this.

```
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1"  />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'s" replacement="" replace="all" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to ignore the special characters, try using the following field type.
This would lower case the words and catenate the words excluding all special chars.

```
    <fieldType name="string_sort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

However, this would not work for 'sAmerica as s is not a special character.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'s" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

If this is fixed pattern you need to replace it before the word delimiter with above.

Edit -- Are you using this config ?

```
<fieldType name="string_sort" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'s" replacement="" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Have tested the following through analysis and it produces the following tokens -

KT - 'sAlgarve
LCF - 'salgarve
PRF - algarve
WDF - algarve

Can you check through the analysis.

Comment: What did not work ? did you associate the field with string_sort field type ? are you using that field for sorting and is marked indexed true ? did you check on the analysis cause I tested for your examples with the above config and it generated correct entries.

Comment: No..this is not working.i did all these things.see my records appears like after applying : 1) Alvor, 2) North 3) Op locatie in 4) 'sAlgarve..which is wrong.this should be 1) 'sAlgarve 2) Alvor 3)North 4) Op locatie in..because we replace 's with ""..

Comment: jsut tell me what would be the output of this records?1) Alvor, 2) North 3) Op locatie in 4) 'sAlgarve..if i apply this filters..

Comment: have attached the output of analysis for 'sAlgarve in the answer per filter.

Comment: i don't know how to do analysis?

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html#Analysis+Debugging  Select the field type string_sort and put the words in the index block and click analysis with verbose if you want. You will see the output per filter.

Comment: thanks.i did analysis.
U are right at all,but this does not work.
Let me explain.I want to sort records like this.
If location that start with 's or 's-,then use the first character after 's or 's- to sort.

Comment: my output is KT - 'sAlgarve
LCF - 'salgarve
PRF - salgarve
WDF - salgarve

Comment: hmm thats strange ... What version of Solr are you using ? can you paste you string_sort field type configuration ?

Comment: It's not the same as suggested. The pattern filter should be added before the word delimiter. In your config its opposite. The word delimiter will remove the ' and hence the pattern 's is never matched and wont be replaced. Please use the config as suggested in the same order.